# How to implement an #if function into a infobox?

Tags: if-statement, mediawiki

So I've been trying to implement an #if parser into an infobox, but I seem to be out of luck. The previous code I used seems to be outdated, and I can't find the a way to code it in again, differentely. :/

Basically, in this infobox, if a field is not typed in(or if typed in is left empty) it should become 'invisible' or not even render.

This code worked fine in a previous version of MediaWiki(not sure which one though), but no longer: http://pastebin.com/uQ49mPbQ. I've been trying to use it as a tutorial, and even outright copy and pasted it, but it simply doesn't work. All of the fields would become invisible, regardless of what I would have done to them...

This is the new code that I am using, and would like to be #if'ed: http://pastebin.com/3j0AbN5v

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: The code you show us looks fine, and [works for me](http://leowallentin.se/smw/w/index.php?title=Test). Can you provide a link to your wiki?

Comment: @leo Here's the old infobox in the new wiki: http://empiresedge.com/library/index.php?title=Template:Testinfobox, and here it is while used: http://empiresedge.com/library/index.php?title=Mox. It is obviously broken, but somehow it worked on the older wiki that I used: http://www.vastempire.com/wiki/Template:Character_infobox, http://www.vastempire.com/wiki/Mox
Works

._.

Comment: Ok, you haven't even enabled the parser functions that you are using, so no wonder it doesn't work. I answered you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the [ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aExtension%3aParserFunctions) to be able to use the `{{#if}}` parser function. Do this in your `LocalSettings.php`:

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/ParserFunctions/ParserFunctions.php" );
```

If you want to use the [string functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aStringFunctions) (like `{{#replace}}`, `{{#explode}}`, etc), also add:

```
$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;
```

In recent versions of MediaWiki, ParserFunctions is included (but not enabled) so you don't need to download anything.

**Basic troubleshooting:** Whenever you see code like `{{#zyx:...}}` in a wiki page, it (probably) means, that someone tried to use a [parser function](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aParser_function) that is not installed. Unless there is a parser function called “zyx” installed, the code `{{#zyx:...}}` has no special meaning to the wiki, and the text will be printed just like it is. The most common parser functions are collected in an extension called ParserFunctions, that is used on WikiMedia wikis. You will need the parser functions from ParserFunctions whenever copying templates from e.g. English Wikipedia.

To see what parser functions you have enabled, navigate to `Special:Version` on your wiki. Below the list of installed extensions is a list of tags (such as `<gallery />`) and parser functions available. As you can see, “if” is among the parser functions on your [old](http://www.vastempire.com/wiki/Special%3aVersion) wiki, but not on your [new](http://empiresedge.com/library/index.php?title=Special%3aVersion).

Comment: Worked like a charm. :D
Thanks!